# Examples of epimorphisms which are not split epimorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Are there some examples of epimorphisms which are not split epimorphisms? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question isn't really focussed. There are lots lots lots of examples, in various categories, for various objects, ...

Comment: In fact,it is harder to find examples where all epis are split, in a sense! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The projection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (in, for example, the category of abelian groups). It has no splitting, because there are no non-trivial homomorphism from  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ due to lack of elements of order two in the latter group.

Comment: "In the category of groups, the projection ..."

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. It is, indeed, essential to specify the category. I guess it was implicit in my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Every split epimorphism is an coequalizer; every coequalizer is an epimorphism. So every non-coequalizer is a non-split epimorphism.

**Addition:** Thanking Zhen Lin, I changed "equalizer" by "coequalizer".

Comment: You mean _coequaliser_.

Comment: @Zhen Lin:Yes, thank you. I will correct the answer.

Comment: This is not an example in the usual sense of the word "example".

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: Of course. It's a way to get examples.

Answer (score 1):

See [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/split-epimorphisms-and-split-monomorphisms/) and [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/epi-mono-factorizations/) for examples. (Any fake isomorphism, in the terminology of the second post, is mono and epi but cannot be either split mono or split epi.) Being split is a very strong condition, and in fact epimorphisms just don't split in general. $\text{Set}$ is a bad place to look for intuition about the different kinds of epimorphisms.